# KHB decomposition after entropy balancing of into direct and Indirect effects

Tags: r

I am esimating the ATT of a treatment variable on binary outcome using R. I balanced the covariate distributions using entropy balancing and estimated two models reduced model and full model. For this I created a survey design which consists weights for each observations obtained with combination of sampling weights and weights obtained from the entropy balancing procedure.

When I do KHB decompostion using following code:

```
des <- svydesign(~1, data = dt, weights=~dt$ral67wtrsp*w.out$weights)
reduced<-svyglm(y~treat,design=des,family=binomial)
summary(reduced)
full<-glm(y~treat+edu+retire, design=des,family=binomial)
summary(full)
khb_model<-khb(reduced,full)
```

I get an error like this during KHB decomposition:

> Mediators: raeducat, r7retemp
> Error in svyglm.survey.design(formula = ratmemorycat ~ rchpov + KHB__KHB__raeducat +  :
> all variables must be in design= argument.
> Any one have the solution to this?